# Hosting HTML/CSS site on Visual Studio hosting service

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2012, localhost, cross-domain

I developed small Restful Web Service in VS2012 which should manipulate with database through entity framework.

Client side is HTML/CSS/JavaScript web site which shows data from database.
Is there any way to communicate by Ajax (to overcome cross domain issue) from my site to Restful Web Service without installing IIS, because I have really bad and slow computer and I need this only for quick test.

Can I host my web site somehow on service which Visual Studio uses to publish Services run by Visual Studio, or there is some other way how to test it quickly ?

Comment: Visual studio comes with IIS Express for debugging.why can't you use that?

Comment: Yes I want to use use IIS Express, but I don know if there is any "public folder" where I can just copy my web site folder so if IIS Express can host it ?  Or I need to make some web project in Visual Studio and start it from Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use `iisexpress` Do this

Publish your website to any folder in your PC.

Then open a `cmd` window and run the following commands

```
cd "C:\Program Files\IIS Express"
```

on 64-bit OS,

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
```

Now the path would change to IIS Express>
Then run the following command

```
iisexpress /path:your\website\path\ /port:8030
```

This will start your website over the port `8030`
IIS express will run as long as you don't close this `cmd` window. You can see `iisexpress` icon in the notification area also.

Easier way is to install `IIS` in your PC and host it with much better options.

Comment: Thank you it solve my first problem to host site. My Restful Service which I run in VS2012 is on URL: "http://localhost:3788/Service1.svc/", and my web site is now on URL: "http://localhost:8030/".   I put them in the same folder on my hard disc but I have cross domain problem, I can not call Restful service methods from my site. Is there any way how I can solve this (to adjust them in the same domain) ?

Comment: is both REST service and your website runs in the same instance of iis express? Then it should work.

Comment: I am not sure how to check it ? I host site following your instructions. Service worked normally until I exit from VS. Probably now I need to host Restful Service in the same instance as my site. Should I do it in the same way as for site ?

Comment: iisexpress invoked from VS will close after you close VS. You can host the rest service in the same way as site in another cmd window with a different port number. Make sure your website calls the rest service to the new address of the rest service.

Comment: Thanks man you helped me a lot. I actually did not run two instances, obviously I do not understand very wall how structure of folder should be that site and service are in the same domain. I copy whole my web site in folder where my service is and host just service, it automatically host my site and no more cross domain issue :).

Comment: Welcome :) . I was about to propose that solution if my suggestion wasn't working. Glad to hear you did it.